# How can I resolve a error while writing a xlsx file with calculation

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I use phpspreadsheet in Version 1.9.0. I load an xls file, fill in some values ans save it to xlsx. No problems.

Today I update to 1.18.0. Now I become an error:

```
    #0 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Database/DatabaseAbstract.php(68): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Database\DatabaseAbstract::buildQuery()
#1 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Database/DatabaseAbstract.php(77): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Database\DatabaseAbstract::filter()
#2 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Database/DSum.php(42): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Database\DatabaseAbstract::getFilteredColumn()
#3 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Statistical/Conditional.php(188): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Database\DSum::evaluate()
#4 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Statistical/Conditional.php(208): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Statistical\Conditional::SUMIF()
#5 [internal function]: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Statistical\Conditional::SUMIFS()
#6 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php(4846): call_user_func_array()
#7 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php(3539): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation-&gt;processTokenStack()
#8 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php(3332): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation-&gt;_calculateFormulaValue()
#9 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php(259): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation-&gt;calculateCellValue()
#10 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Worksheet.php(1229): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell-&gt;getCalculatedValue()
#11 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Worksheet.php(1300): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet-&gt;writeCellFormula()
#12 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Worksheet.php(1156): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet-&gt;writeCell()
#13 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Worksheet.php(70): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet-&gt;writeSheetData()
#14 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php(377): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet-&gt;writeWorksheet()
#15 /home/kursdatis/kursdatis/subsites/anwesenheitxls.php(182): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx-&gt;save()
#16 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/kursdatis/kursdatis/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Database/DatabaseAbstract.php</b> on line <b>112</b><br />
```

I dont know what I can do to handle this. I check the xls file row for row column for column and found problem in a calculation. But I dont know what I can do to fix the problem.

This calculation is in the cell:

```
=_xlfn.SUMIFS($E$11:$AI$11,$E14:$AI14,"e")+_xlfn.SUMIFS($E$11:$AI$11,$E14:$AI14,"")
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with formula pre-calculation. The following worked for me when migrating from 1.6.0 to 1.18.0.

Try setting PreCalculateFormulas to false before outputting the file, as per this example from the documentation :

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save("05featuredemo.xlsx");
```

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/